# Author template - separate custom post type by custom taxonomy term for $curauth

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, author, terms, author-template

Basically I have a post type called photograph, I then have a Taxonomy group called "Subject" and several tax terms i.e. Abstract, freeze frame etc (Approx 18 in total) under that Taxonomy group.

I then have a custom author template, where it displays the current authors posts (which are CPT's) and I am looking for a way to output the following for the current author:

```
<h2>Term 1</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>Photograph cpt, term 1, post 1</li>
    <li>Photograph cpt, term 1, post 2</li>
    <li>Photograph cpt, term 1, post 3</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Term 2</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>Photograph cpt, term 2, post 1</li>
    <li>Photograph cpt, term 2, post 2</li>
    <li>Photograph cpt, term 2, post 3</li>
    </ul>

    etc...
```

I am seriously desperate, and would very much appreciate any help or direction with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. Can you update the question to make it more clear what the desired result would be please.

Comment: Hey t31os, Sorry my lack of experience and jargon, probably makes my question read like hieroglyphics... I have updated it.

Comment: And are you expecting these posts to have only a single term in this taxonomy? Else what output do you expect when there are term intersections, ie. a post has several of those terms(and not just one, per your example).

Comment: Oh, It would be great if that post displayed under each term. i.e. if checked for 3 terms it should display under each of those 3 terms... Hope that answers your question :) thanks

Comment: as they will be display using jQuery in a gallery type manner. each term will be a button, that when clicked will display the relevant posts for that term.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, encase anyone else needs it, here it is.

```
<?php

$currauthor_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');

$terms = get_terms('your_taxonomy', array(

     'orderby'    => 'name',         

         'order'    => 'ASC',

     'hide_empty' => 1,

    ) );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {       

    $myquery = new WP_Query( array(

        'author' => $currauthor_id,

        'post_type' => 'post_type_name',

        'your_taxonomy' => $term->slug,

        'posts_per_page' = > -1,

        ));

?>

    <h2>Term: <?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>

    <ul>

    <?php if ( $myquery->have_posts() ){ 

        while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post(); ?>

            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

    <?php endwhile; } ?>

    </ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>        

<?php } ?>
```